# Python script using p.stdout.read() stty: standard input: Invalid argument

Tags: python

Trying to run a python script that uses SUDO SU -  and passes control to a shell to run a ksh script.  It works fine but stdout is giving me an error that I would like to resolve

Calling this by either ANSIBLE Tower or directly:  python test.py NEWPASS

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
Python script for Oracle
Called by the following
        SYS_SYSTEM_PASSWORD_CHANGE {{PASSWD}}
'''

import os
import sys
import re
import argparse
import textwrap
import subprocess
#import commands

# RUNPROC process.
def runproc():
    print('RUNNING PASSWORD CHANGE')
    cmds = ['sudo su - ' +runas +'/orasoft/scripts/password_change.ksh ' +npass]
    p = subprocess.Popen('/bin/bash', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    for cmd in cmds:
      print(cmd)
      p.stdin.write(cmd)
    p.stdin.close()
    print(p.stdout.read())

def get_command():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG',formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
           description=textwrap.dedent('''\
              '''))
    parser.add_argument('passwd')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    global npass
    npass = args.passwd
    print('NEW PASS:  ' +npass)

    proc = subprocess.Popen("ls -latr /etc/oratab | tr -s ' ' | cut -f3 -d' '",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    global runas
    (runas, err) = proc.communicate()
    #runas = runas.decode("utf-8")
    print('RUNNING AS:  ' +runas)
    #print(runas.decode("utf-8"))

    runproc()

# -- begin fetching commands
get_command()
```

Everything is passed correctly and the scripts are being called correctly, but I'm not understanding the invalid argument error
Here is the output from a test:

```
CDB001@y81dev00-> python test.py NEWPASS
NEW PASS:  NEWPASS
RUNNING AS:  oracle

RUNNING PASSWORD CHANGE
sudo su - oracle
/orasoft/scripts/password_change.ksh NEWPASS

**stty: standard input: Invalid argument**
CHANGING PASSWORDS ON:     DATABASE:  CDB001  NEW_PASSWORD:  NEWPASS  RUNNING AS:  oracle

NAME
---------
CDB001
```

Comment: Use `communicate` (again) instead of `write`-`close`-`read` to avoid the risk of deadlock.

Comment: Your `/bin/bash` process doesn’t need `shell=True` (and thus shouldn’t use it).

Comment: It *may* be the shell initialization for `oracle` that’s running `stty`; try without the `-` argument to `su`?

Comment: This script is being called from Ansible for any given host.  Python is new to me and I'm learning by trial and error.  I thought I needed to use stdin like I have in order to run multiple commands under the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the dash (-) from the sudo su resolved the error.
Thank you!